# Is it possible to create a Substate type in Python that removes the first section of a Literal type?

Tags: python, types, mypy, pylance

I have a Python `Literal` type that includes various period separated strings. I would like to also have a `Literal` type that includes the same strings but without the first period-delimited section. I could manually do this, but I don't want to do that every time I need to remove a section.

```py
from typing import Literal

# Period-delimited string literals
ActiveState = Literal['active.green', 'active.yellow', 'active.red']
State = ActiveState | OtherState | AnotherState # I'd like to do this with multiple

# Remove the first period-delimited section for when we're only looking at stuff after that
def handle_active_state(substate: Literal['green', 'yellow', 'red']) -> None: ...
```

I've tried using `typing.get_args` to iterate over and modify the values in `ActiveState`, but I was unable to then find a way to use those values in a new `Literal` type. I tried using `types.GenericAlias` to recreate the `Literal`, but it thought the result was a value and not a type or type alias when I tried to use it.

```py
from typing import Literal, get_args
from types import GenericAlias
ActiveState = Literal['active.green', 'active.yellow', 'active.red']

ActiveSubstate = GenericAlias(Literal, tuple('.'.join(state.split('.')[1:]) for state in get_args(ActiveState)))
# While this does generate Literal['green', 'yellow', 'red'], it's not usable

def handle_active_state(substate: ActiveSubstate) -> None: ...
# pylance: Illegal type annotation: variable not allowed unless it is a type alias
# Also encountered similar issue with mypy
```

My goal is to be able to make some sort of reusable type that does this automatically. For example, something like `Substate[ActiveState]` would be ideal. Is this possible in Python? If not, why is not possible?

### Edit:

This is for static type analysis. This kind of static type analysis does work in some other languages too. [Example of this working in TypeScript:](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggxsAlgNwgZWAQ2NAvFAckwRQgDoBzAJwggDsCoAfQ4pVMkCAG24HsA7oxZESHGgBMCAbgBQoSFDQBXAEYBnLDgA8AFQB8UfLqgQAHjjoT1UAAYASAN6I6AMwhUoAMURVNAXzInF3dPGFccKn9bKAB%20WAiPKAAuKF05BWh4dnQ1TWw8JTytCG1s0gwC-TlZOD46TSgKPj4JVPLUFQ0So0JqWgY5OobgKFVMNtgxXO6C3oJVbmUIGVkgA)

```js
type ActiveState = 'active.green' | 'active.yellow' | 'active.red';
type Substate<T> = T extends `${infer First}.${infer After}` ? After : T;
type ActiveSubstate = Substate<ActiveState>;

const good: ActiveSubstate = 'green';
const bad: ActiveSubstate = 'blue'; // As expected: Type '"blue"' is not assignable to type 'ActiveSubstate'.
```

Comment: it's unclear what your purposes are. IS this for *annotating* a type for the purposes of static analysis tools like mypy, pylance? You are trying to *dynamically* do that, but you can't. The whole point is that these are *static annotations*. What you are doing are just not valid annotations.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for [literal evaluation](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/11990); yes, it's possible, but just not developed yet; it's trivial (but tedious) to write a mypy plugin to do this. For the large majority of use cases, these are dynamic operations on *session-defined constants and literals*, and since mypy operates by analysing Python code *and is written in Python itself*, and mypy has access to both `str` methods and literal values, for type-checking purposes it's perfectly plausible to "statically" evaluate something like `'.'.join(state.split('.')[1:])`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga This *is* for the purposes of annotating a type for static analysis tools. TypeScript is already capable of things like this. I'll add an example to my post.

Comment: @Andria Python and TypeScript have two very different typing systems. Typescript is a *structurally typed* system, so these sorts of tools are natural to that. Python is nominally typed (with some limited support for structural typing with `typing.Protocol`). In general, you are going to be disappointed if you want Python's type system to work like TypeScript's.

Comment: In any case, as far as I am aware, there is not support for what you want to do here in PEP 484, 483 or the subsequent PEPs that further extend Python's type annotation system. I'm afraid you may be SOL

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Is it possible to make some version of this with `typing.Protocol` then? Doesn't have to closely resemble the whole strings and dots thing. I'm mostly just going for the concept of being able to extract the substate from a state type.

Comment: @dROOOze Do you know if it would be possible to write a plugin for this in pylance too?

Comment: The pyright devs are not interested in allowing plugins for pyright - see https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/issues/607